# Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You may not set `id` as an attribute on your model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Entire error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You may not set `id` as an attribute on your model. Please remove any lines that look like: `id: DS.attr('<type>')` from App.Plan
```

Ember Model:

```
App.Plan = DS.Model.extend({
id: DS.attr('number'),
name: DS.attr('string'),
period: DS.attr('number'),
price: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Data coming from REST API:

```
{"plans":[{"id":1,"name":"Monthly subscription","period":1,"price":2}]}
```

**Question:** How can I move around the above error ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just leave out the `id` attribute from your `DS.Model`. Ember-data automatically handles that for you. You'll still be able to find the record using the id, and it'll be a property on the object when you access it from within your Ember application. [See here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/#toc_core-concepts) and [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_id) for more info.

```
App.Plan = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  period: DS.attr('number'),
  price: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Comment: Yeah tried it now again, didn't work first time because i was using it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: How do I make $E.toJSON() return the id as well as the other attributes?