# deleteRecord with multiple belongsTo relationships in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, has-many, belongs-to, ember-cli

**What is the ember-cli best practice to deleteRecord() on a model that belongsTo multiple models?  Do I have to manually clean up relationships on the parents?**

Migrating from ember to ember-cli I am having new trouble with deleteRecord() for a model 'star' that belongsTo multiple models, 'post' and 'user'.  Before moving to ember cli it was working with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18818441/1083851).

[**The previous solution's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18818441/1083851) delete action fails in the current ember-cli with errors and **never calls the api**.  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelFor' of undefined` and `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelFor' of undefined` at the line

```
var inverse = relationship.parentType.inverseFor(name);
// name is the string 'post'
```

**Now I'm starting simple again.**  Here is a simple example of what I'm trying.  Maybe I am missing something with es6, explicit inverses, or using `needs:`?

`http://localhost:4200/post/1`

[image: deleteRecord() on child model not cleaning parent relations]

**models**

```
// models/star.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  created: DS.attr('date'),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post', {
    async: true,
    inverse: 'stars'
  }),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {
    async: true,
    inverse: 'stars'
  })
});


// models/post.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  headline: DS.attr(),
  body: DS.attr(),
  stars: DS.hasMany('star', { async: true })
});


// models/users.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr(),
  stars: DS.hasMany('star', { async: true })
});
```

**controller**

```
//controllers/post.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    createStar: function(){
      var self=this,
          post = this.get('model'),
          user = this.store.find('user', 2),
          star;

      user.then( function(user){
        star = self.get('store').createRecord('star', {
          post: post,
          user: user
        });
        star.save().then( function(star){
          post.get('stars').then( function(stars){
            stars.pushObject(star);
          });
          user.get('stars').then( function(stars){
            stars.pushObject(star);
          });
        });
      });

    },
    deleteStar: function() {
      var user = this.store.find('user', 2),
          self = this;

      user.then( function(user){
        var filtered = self.get('stars').filterProperty('user.id', user.id);
        var star = filtered[0];

        star.deleteRecord();
        star.save();
      });
      return(false);
    }
  }
});
```

**Update: Alternate `deleteStar` `post` controller action re: @jjwon**

```
deleteStar: function() {
  var user = this.store.find('user', 2),
      self = this;

  user.then( function(user){

    var stars = self.get('stars').then( function(items){

      // log the post's stars before delete
      items.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item);
      });

      var filtered = items.filterBy('user.id', user.id);
      var star = filtered.get('firstObject');

      star.deleteRecord();
      star.save().then(function(){

        // log the post's stars after delete
        items.forEach(function(item) {
          console.log(item);
        });
      }); 
    });
  });
  return(false);
}
```

Interestingly I found that if I add a star, reload the page, then delete it, that the star is successfully removed from the post's stars. Great!

**But if I add a star and remove it without reloading, there is still a reference to the removed star with its `id` among the post's stars.** Looking in the console, the removed star object is still referenced by the post with its `id`, but the `user` and `post` attributes are `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`stars` is an async attribute of `user`.  Therefore, when you have:

```
var filtered = self.get('stars').filterProperty('user.id', user.id);
var star = filtered[0];

star.deleteRecord();
star.save();
```

`filtered` might be a promise, so this might not be working as expected.  Also, I'm not too familiar with filterProperty, but you don't have an attribute called `user.id` so it seems like that might be returning an empty list?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I updated the question with a revised `post` controller action to experiment with your suggestions.  Still haven't gotten it to work.

I think I'll try another stab at making (this solution)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/18818441/1083851] work in ember-cli.

Comment: Change notes based on your suggestions:
- `stars` is a promise, so I use a `.then()` function
- I noticed different behaviour if I refresh before deleting (see update)
- ember-data automatically handles the id attribute http://stackoverflow.com/a/24559143/1083851

Comment: Also, I swapped `filterBy` for `filterProperty` (deprecated), same usage. It is an enumerable method, does not appear to return a promise. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterBy http://stackoverflow.com/a/16925654/1083851

Comment: in your new deleteStart method, also remove the star from the 'stars' collection, stars.removeObject(star).

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm cleaning up the relationships on the parents very manually.  This works but isn't ideal.

```
deleteStar: function() {
  var user = this.store.find('user', 2),
      self = this;

  user.then( function(user){
    var star = self.get('stars').filterBy('user.id', user.id).get('firstObject');

    // clean up relationships on parents very manually 
    // user.stars
    user.get('stars').removeObject(star);
    // posts.stars
    self.get('stars').removeObject(star);

    star.deleteRecord();
    star.save();

  });
  return(false);
}
```

Comment: This is also the path I'm going down, but it would be awesome if Ember knew to remove the relationships automatically when a record was deleted.